# ComponentLookupException when importing java project into intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just download a spring boot project from https://start.spring.io/ and imported it into intellij idea, then I choose import module selecting the pom.xml file but when I click on Apply I get the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp.tutorials</groupId>
    <artifactId>rabbitmq-amqp-tutorials</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rabbitmq-amqp-tutorials</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**EDIT:SOLUTION**

As pointed out by @Sanura Hettiarachchi there is a bug with the edition of intellij idea I was using, uninstalling and installing the latest version (Intellij Idea 2022.2.3 Community Edition) solved the problem. Now importing an existing project works nicely, no need to manually import modules.

Comment: The first suspicious issue: why do you need to import the module again after you opened the existing project? Did you pick the wrong settings on the import there? Also: Do you have any repository or mirror configuration inside your local maven settings.xml? And please extend the first text error message with "the following errors" it refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. You click "open or import" and add the existing project. After that you try to import the same project again.

If you want to load the maven dependancies right click on the "pom.xml" and select "maven->reload project"

**Update:**
The issue seems to be on intelliJ IDE older versions which should be fixed by now.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-290419/Maven-385-NoSuchMethodError-orgapachemavenmodelvalidationDefaultModelValidator-method-void-init-not-found

Comment: it's not like I am trying to import the same project twice. Look at the third screenshot (taken right after I import the project) there's no directories in there, no src, .mvn, .idea folders.
If (when I am at the third screenshot) I try to pom.xml > Maven > Import as Maven project nothing happens.
Meanwhile If I add a module the those folders appear but I get the error shown in my question.

Comment: BTW if you have any guidelines on how to add a project in intellij please point me to it because I swear to god it's always such a pain.

Comment: That's weird that it's not showing directories at the first time. Your IDE version is a bit old. That should not be a problem though.

Comment: I created this video for you,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SI4Y6DmAmgM&ab_channel=SanuraHettiarachchi

Comment: Thank you for your time! Unfortunately I could not reproduce what's shown in your video. Here's mine if u wanna take a look https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B01y4A38D0g

Comment: This is a bug in the IDE.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-290419/Maven-385-NoSuchMethodError-orgapachemavenmodelvalidationDefaultModelValidator-method-void-init-not-found
Update to the latest version and it will work.

Comment: Or downgrade your maven version.
File > Setting > Build Execution... > Build tools > Maven > Maven home path
 3.8.X to 3.6.X

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249225/discussion-between-sanura-hettiarachchi-and-idk).

Comment: thank you but there's no need, you pointed me in the right direction. I will edit my question with the solution, thank you.